# using lapply on a data table within a function in R

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm currently working on a piece of code that would calculate how many observations are lost within a group of study participants, if a certain data cleaning criteria is applied. This specific example has to do with making sure the age ratio of each study is balanced. In this code I would be testing two age drop criterion (ratios of 4 and 5).

Given the data table containing all data on every study participant (*cgf.dt*) and the two age drop criterion to test (*age.drop.criteria*), I would like my function to calculate how many are lost for each age criterion and output the resulting numbers as a list.

Below is the code I have written:

```
age.drop.criteria <- c(4, 5)
age_ratio_check <- function(cgf.dt, age.drop.criteria) {
  age.dt<-cgf.dt
  message("there are ",
          age_count<-age.dt[abs(age_ratio-1)>age.drop.criteria] %>%      
            uniqueN(by=c('nid', 'source', 'admin_1')),
          " groups that have unreasonable age ratio. \n see admin 1s below:")
  age.dt[abs(age_ratio-1)>age.drop.criteria, paste0(ihme_loc_id, "->",  
                                                    admin_1) %>% table]
  age.dt <- age.dt[!(abs(age_ratio-1)>age.drop.criteria)]

}
lapply(age.drop.criteria, age_ratio_check)
```

After running this code, I get the following error:

> Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'age_ratio' not found

I have checked my data table and the variable age_ratio is present. I'm wondering if someone can help me resolve this error and get my code to run through properly. Thank you for taking the time to read my post!

Comment: `lapply(X, FUN, ...)` builds the function like `FUN(X[[1]], ...)` but you seem to want to use the second argument to the fun. You can just be more explicit: `lapply(age.drop.criteria, function(x) age_ratio_check(cgf.dt, x))`

Comment: That is difficult code to read let alone understand. I would avoid tidyverse pipes `>%>` inside data.table `[]` calls.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for explaining that. I tried this in my code, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition of `age_ratio` in you function, dude.

Check this part of code:

```
 message("there are ",
          age_count<-age.dt[abs(age_ratio-1)>age.drop.criteria] %>%      
            uniqueN(by=c('nid', 'source', 'admin_1')),
          " groups that have unreasonable age ratio. \n see admin 1s below:")

  age.dt[abs(age_ratio-1)>age.drop.criteria, paste0(ihme_loc_id, "->",  
                                                    admin_1) %>% table]
  age.dt <- age.dt[!(abs(age_ratio-1)>age.drop.criteria)]
```

abs(age_ratio-1) - there is no definition of this variable 'age_ratio'

You should understand, that in your case there is no variable capturing. You should pass it through parameters or use global.env for retrieving it in your function body.